# Trying to insert a row from a Plugin

Tags: plugins, mysql

```
   <?php

    require_once("../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php");

    wpdb::insert( 'wp_options', array( 'option_name' => 'data1', 'option_value' => 'data2' ) );

    ?>
```

I have this code not working...It gets the following message

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in url/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1684

Of course the file `wp-db.php` is not edited.

I will appreciate any feedback from anyone :)

---

It did not work either...

I tried in both ways and I've got the following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in url/insert-row.php on line 12
```

Anyway I can´t use my own instance for security purposes...

Answer (score 1):

`insert` is not a static method. So you can't call it like this: `wpdb::insert(/*...*/)`.

You'll need to do something like:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert(/*...*/);
```

Or create your own instance:

```
$db = new wpdb('dbuser', 'dbpassword', 'dbname', 'dbhost'); // change these!
$db->insert(/*...*/);
```

Answer (score -1):

I've solved the problem!

I was getting a NULL result on

```
var_dump($wpdb);
```

I only had to add the following:

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

Done! Thank you ChrisGuitarGuy!

Comment: That means you are calling the PHP file not in a WordPress context. **Never** include `wp-load.php` from a plugin. You cannot know where it really it, because the plugin directory can be moved.